# Control sound in embedded swf in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, flash, actionscript-2

I have an external .swf I have loaded into flash, and I don't have control over what code is in this .swf.  I have it loaded into a movieclip in my scene, and I want to control the volume of the sounds in this loaded .swf.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `flash.media.SoundMixer` class you are able to control all sound in an application. You can think of it as the master volume control on a mixer table. I believe this also applies to externally loaded SWF's.

```
var volume:Number = 0.5;
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(volume);
```